# Subclassing JavaScript arrays - constructor arguments not passing to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, prototype

I want to subclass a javascript Array and pass constructor arguments to the array. What I have is:

```
function SubArray(arguments) {
    Array.apply(this, arguments);
}

SubArray.prototype = Array.prototype;
```

Test does not indicate that arguments are being passed to the Array

```
var x = new SubArray("One", "Two", "Three");
// Object[]
// x.length = 0
```

Whereas when I do this with an Array I get this

```
var x = new Array("One", "Two", "Three");
// Object["One", "Two", "Three"]
// x.length = 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _Array_ is a _DOM host Object_, sadly you can't extend it like this :( as you saw, `.length` won't work as expected, `.apply` won't work as expected, you have to create a normal _Array_ instance and add properties to it as desired

Comment: You need ES6 in order to subclass the Array object.  It is considered an exotic object (due to its peculiar `.length` property) that has issues when trying to subclass in ES5 or earlier.

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ES6

In ES6 you can extend *Array* using the `class` syntax

```
class SubArray extends Array {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
    }
    first() {
        return this[0];
    }
}
```

*length* will work as expected

```
var sa = new SubArray('foo', 'bar');
sa[2] = 'baz';
sa.length; // 3
sa.first(); // "foo"
sa instanceof SubArray; // true
```

---

### Pre-ES5

Up to and including ES5 there is no way to cleanly extend `Array` in the usual constructor-prototype way without losing functionality, instead you have to add properties to an Array instance

```
function SubArray() {
    var arr = Array.apply(null, arguments);
    arr.first = function () {return this[0];};
    return arr;
}
```

Using this no longer requires `new` as an *Object* is returned from the function, and `instanceof` will not be able to determine *SubArray*.

```
var sa = SubArray('foo', 'bar');
sa[2] = 'baz';
sa.length; // 3
sa.first(); // "foo"
sa instanceof SubArray; // false -- this gets broken
```

---

### ES5 (slow)

In an ES5 environment where behaviour is more important than speed, you can force the prototype chain as desired using [`Object.setPrototypeOf` **(see MDN warning)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf), this is *"a bit of a hack"* and would look like

```
function SubArray() {
    var arr = Array.apply(null, arguments);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(arr, SubArray.prototype);
    return arr;
}
SubArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
SubArray.prototype.first = function () {return this[0];};
```

Again, `new` is no-longer required but this time the behaviour of instances is exactly as would be expected if it was extended normally.

```
var sa = SubArray('foo', 'bar');
sa[2] = 'baz';
sa.length; // 3
sa.first(); // "foo"
sa instanceof SubArray; // true
```

Comment: Presumably though, ES6 is not fully adopted yet, therefore compatibility issues may arise?

Comment: @series0ne Yes, even in browsers like _Chrome_ you have to be in `"use strict";` for it to work at the moment. I've provided an ES5 solution too

Comment: I'm a bit late but to summarize: `function SubArray() { return Array.apply(this, arguments) }; SubArray.prototype = Array.prototype; new SubArray("One", "Two", "Three")` works pretty fine just as well.

Comment: @Lapys if you do that then add something to `SubArray.prototype` it also gets added to `Array.prototype` (as it is the same object), so you've polluted `Array.prototype` with the _SubArray_ code