# Weird Array Objects - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Arrays are quite something in JavaScript when compared with other programming languages and it's not without its full set of quirks.

Including this one:

```
// Making a normal array.
var normalArray = [];
normalArray.length = 0;

normalArray.push(1);
normalArray[1] = 2;

normalArray; // returns [1, 2]
normalArray.length // returns 2
```

So yes, the above is how we all know to make arrays and fill them with elements, right? (ignore the `normalArray.length = 0` part for now)

But why is it that when the same sequence is applied on an object that's not purely an array, it looks a bit different and its `length` property is off by a bit?

```
// Making an object that inherits from the array prototype (i.e.: custom array)
var customArray = new (function MyArray() {
    this.__proto__ = Object.create(Array.prototype);
    return this
});
customArray.length = 0;

customArray.push(1);
customArray[1] = 2;

customArray; // returns [1, 1: 2]
customArray.length // returns 1
```

Not entirely sure what's going on here but some explanation will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801251/subclassing-javascript-arrays-constructor-arguments-not-passing-to-array probably related

Comment: Thanks, but the question from the link 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801251/subclassing-javascript-arrays-constructor-arguments-not-passing-to-array' is not entirely related.

It asks about inheritance of the Array prototype by custom objects; Which is not the question of why adding elements (in different ways) to custom arrays & normal arrays seems kinda dodgy.

Comment: *"Up to and including ES5 there is **no way to cleanly extend Array** in the usual constructor-prototype way **without losing functionality**, instead you have to add properties to an Array instance"* A custom array would be an extension of `Array` would it not?

Comment: Hmm, you do have a point there. And yes, a custom array would basically be an extension of `Array`.

Does this really propose that there is no way to invalidate this odd behavior of arrays..?

You quoted something, can I see where you got the reference there?

Comment: The accepted answer of the question that i linked ;). You can find similar reports by looking up subclassing or extending javascript arrays using your favourite search engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the perfect answer, but according to my understanding of Javascript arrays, they are a little bit different than usual objects. (Mainly due to the fact that it maintains a length property, and Objects don't).

So if we take your code for an example:

```
var normalArray = [];
```

This is the right way to create an array in Javascript. But what about the below one?

```
var customArray = new (function MyArray() {
    this.__proto__ = Object.create(Array.prototype);
    return this
});
```

Are they same? Let's see..

```
Array.isArray(normalArray); // true -> [object Array]
Array.isArray(customArray); // false -> [object Object]
```

So it is clear that although you inherit from the array prototype, it doesn't really create an object with `Array` type. It just creates a plain JS object, but with the inherited array functions. That's the reason why it updates the length when you set the value with `customArray.push(1);`.

But since your `customArray` is only a regular object and for a regular JS object, `[]` notation is used to set a property, it doesn't update the length (because `Objects` don't have a `length` property)

Hope it's clear :)

Answer (score 1):

The array you are trying to create is not a pure array (as you are perhaps aware). Its basically a JavaScript object and is supposed to behave like an object.

While treating an object like an array, its up to you to maintain all it's array like features.

You specifically have to assign a `length` property to it and you did it correctly.

Next, the `push` method from `Array.prototype` is supposed to insert an element to the array and increment the `length` property (if any), so it did increment 0 to 1. There you go, the `length` now is 1.

Next you used the literal notation of property assignment to `Object`, which is similar to something like `customArray['someProperty'] = 1`.

While using literal notation, no method from `Array.Prototype` is being invoked and hence the customArray object never knows that it has to behave like an Array and its length property remains unaffected. It simply behaves like an object and you get what you got.

Remember the `length` is just a property on Array class and this property is appropriately incremented and decremented by every method on Array.

**Note: Array like objects are not recommended and its up to you entirely to maintain the index and other Array stuff for such objects.**

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you have a problem with your function:

```
return this
```

This should be

```
return (this);
```

Just fixes any potential errors you might have. Another thing is you're not using the `var` keyword to declare `customArray`. These errors might be breaking your code.

Comment: First, thanks for noticing I didn't initialize the array objects properly;

Second, I tried the `(this)` and it didn't change anything;

Third, I'm more interested on what's going on here than solving the problem. I need to know what the problem is that causes such behavior before I try to solve it.

Thanks for the answer though, very well received.

Comment: To add on, the body of the `customArray`'s constructor: `MyArray` doesn't seem to affect the results either. Removing the body entirely does nothing different.

Or maybe I'm not just seeing the obvious here.

Comment: I was just pointing out syntax errors that might have had an effect on your code

Comment: @JBDouble05 I was not aware that there would be a difference when using parenthesis `()` around `this`. Could you point out some reference / explanation of what is changing in the JS syntax ? I failed to find any relevant info.

Comment: Sorry, it's just good syntax to do so. It might just be a strict browser you're using.

Comment: I agree with that the use of the semicolon `;` is indeed good syntax, because it avoid some subtle potential errors, but the parenthesis part seems overkill to me, and I wouldn't rate that "good syntax". Thank you for the clarification.